# adding an uncertain number of fields using javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, dynamically-generated

I'm new to javascript and a novice programmer, so this might be a really easy question to answer. I would like to loop over the values of x number of fields and add them up to display the sum in a final field. I can perform this function if I explicitly call each field, but I want to abstract this so I can deal with a flexible number of fields. Here's example code I've come up with (that's not working for me). Where am I going wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function startAdd(){
    interval = setInterval("addfields()",1);
}
function addfields(){
    a = document.addition.total.value;
    b = getElementByTagName("sum").value;
    for (i=0; i<=b.length; i++){
        a+=i;
    }
    return a;
}
function stopAdd(){
    clearInterval(interval);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<form name="addition">

 <input type="text" name="sum" onFocus="startAdd();" onBlur="stopAdd;">
+ <input type="text" name="sum" onFocus="startAdd();" onBlur="stopAdd;">
= <input type="text" name ="total">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two things wrong with your code.

The first one:

```
b = getElementByTagName("sum").value;
```

You probably mean to `getElementsByTagName` (notice the extra `s`).  Also, there are no `<sum>` elements, which is a problem, because you'll get no results.  Finally, `.value` would return the `value` property of the array (and because none exists, you'll get back `undefined`), and not an array of the `value` properties of each element.

To solve these problems, you can write it like this:

```
inputElements = getElementsByTagName('input');
sumValues = [ ];

for(i = 0; i < inputElements.length; ++i) {
    if(inputElements[i].name == 'sum') {
        sumValues.push(inputElements[i].value);
    }
}
```

Or in jQuery:

```
sumValues = $('input[name=sum]').map(function() {
    return this.value;
});
```

The second one:

```
for (i=0; i<=b.length; i++){
```

`b.length` describes the number of elements.  With `<=`, you are then accessing `b[b.length]`, which doesn't exist.  You want to access up to `b[b.length - 1]`, so the most idiomatic way to write this is to rewrite the condition to use `<` instead of `<=`.  That is:

```
for(i = 0; i < b.length; ++i) {
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no tags in your code named 'sum'. I'd suggest using a class attribute on your input tags and then using `getElementsByTagName('input')` and checking they have the relevant class. jQuery would simplify this enormously, because you would be able to select all elements with a certain class in a single line: `$(".className")`. If you don't want jQuery, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933602/how-to-getelementbyclass-instead-of-getelementbyid-with-javscript) might be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the jQuery Library and do a pattern match to get all the elements you want to add and then put that in your output field