# Javascript: Hide elements by class name

Tags: javascript

I have an html element that I want to hide from view, but I can't access that element by an ID because it has no ID and I can't assign an ID to it.  It has a class assigned to it though.  Is there any possible way to hide this element from view without having it's id?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to getElementByClass instead of GetElementById with Javscript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933602/how-to-getelementbyclass-instead-of-getelementbyid-with-javscript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's `getElementsByClassName` in some browsers, but it's not as widely supported as `getElementById`. Note that it yields an array of elements, instead of just a single element, as several elements can have the same class.

If you can assign an ID to a parent you might be able to access it in some other way:

```
document.getElementById('parent').getElementsByTagName('div')[3] // or whatever
```

Comment: okay... I can access it through a parent id.  How would I go about hiding it from view after I've accessed it?

Comment: nevermind, I figured it out...
var elements = document.getElementById('home_poll').getElementsByTagName('a'); 
 elements[2].style.display = "none";

Answer (score 2):

The following html file contains code to toggle, hide, show div by class and id.
By using class it is possible to hide a set(group) of divisions.

```
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    /*function to toggle visibility of class*/
            function toggle_visibility(classname) { $("."+classname).toggle(); }
    /*function to hide class*/
            function hide_visibility(classname) { $("."+classname).hide(); }
    /*function to show class*/
            function show_visibility(classname) { $("."+classname).show(); }
    /*function to hide individual div by id*/
            function hide_visibility(classname) { $("#"+classname).hide(); }
    /*function to show individual div by id*/       
            function show_visibility(classname) { $("#"+classname).show(); }
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <button onclick="toggle_visibility('class1');">Toggle visibility of class 1</button><br/>
    <button onclick="hide_visibility('class1');">Hide class 1</button><br/>
    <button onclick="show_visibility('class1');">Show class 1</button><br/>
    <button onclick="show_visibility('heading1');">Show heading 1</button><br/>
    <button onclick="hide_visibility('heading1');">Hide heading 1</button><br/>

    <div class="class1" id="heading1"><h1>Heading 1</h1></div>
    <div class="class1"><h2>Heading 2</h2></div>
    <div class="class1"><h3>Heading 3</h3></div>
    <div class="class1"><h4>Heading 4</h4></div>
    <div class="class1"><h5>Heading 5</h5></div>
    <div class="class1"><h6>Heading 6</h6></div>

</body>
```