# Hiding multiple div using same id

Tags: javascript, jsp

I want to hide multiple div using the same script function.is it possible? i have hide one div... check my code

**html code:**

```
<div id="bookingDiv">
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <table>
               <tr>
                  <td class="labelTd">
                     <label>Employee Name
                     </label>
                  </td>
                  <td class="fieldTd">
                     <input type="text" class="txt-med2" style="color: blue" name="txtEmployeeName"  id="txtEmployeeName" readonly tabindex="6" value="<%=strEmployeeName%>" size="11" maxlength="11" />
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td class="labelTd">
                     <label> Travel Date From
                     </label>
                  </td>
                  <td class="fieldTd">
                     <input type="text" class="txt-med2" style="color: blue"  id="txtDateFrom"   readonly name="txtDateFrom" size="11" maxlength="11" tabindex="4"    value="<%=strDateFrom%>"   style=" width : 136px;" />
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td class="labelTd">
                     <label> Purpose of Visit 
                     </label>
                  </td>
                  <td class="fieldTd">
                     <input type="text" class="txt-med2" style="color: blue"  name="txtPurposeOfVisit"  value="<%=strPurpose%>" class="textArea-Medium" tabindex="5" style=" width : 144px;"></input>
                  </td>
                  <td></td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </td>
         <td>
            <table>
               <tr>
                  <td class="labelTd">
                     <label>Designation
                     </label>
                  </td>
                  <td class="fieldTd">
                     <input type="text" class="txt-med2" style="color: blue" name="txtDesignation"  readonly id="txtDesignation" tabindex="8" value="<%=strDesignation%>" size="11"  maxlength="11" />
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td class="labelTd">
                     <label>Employee Grade
                     </label>
                  </td>
                  <td class="fieldTd">
                     <input type="text" class="txt-med2" style="color: blue" name="txtEmployeeGrade"  readonly id="txtEmployeeGrade" tabindex="7" value="<%=strEmployeeGrade%>" size="11" maxlength="11" />
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td class="labelTd">
                     <label>Advance&nbsp;Amount Requested
                     </label>
                  </td>
                  <td class="fieldTd">
                     <input type="text" class="txt-med2" style="color: blue" name="txtAdvanceAmountReq"  readonly id="txtAdvanceAmountReq" tabindex="10" value="<%=approvedAmt%>" size="8"  maxlength="11" />
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td class="labelTd">
                     <label>Additional&nbsp;Amount Requested
                     </label>
                  </td>
                  <td class="fieldTd">
                     <input type="text" class="txt-med2" style="color: blue" name="txtAdditionalAmountReq"  readonly id="txtAdditionalAmountReq" tabindex="11" value="<%=strAdditionalAmountReq%>" size="8" maxlength="11" />
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

**JS code:**

```
function showDiv() {
    var tmp1 = document.getElementById("txtTravelId");
    if (tmp1.value == "") {
        document.getElementById("bookingDiv").style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        document.getElementById("bookingDiv").style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Comment: we cannot do that using id's so try using class. id should be unique for each

Comment: It really isn't clear what you are trying to do. Your question title implies that you are writing invalid HTML (which is a *terrible* idea, don't do that) while your HTML shows a layout table (eugh) with a bunch of labels that aren't associated with any inputs (see the for attribute) and then some JS which doesn't refer to anything in the HTML!

Comment: Your javascript is using ID `bookingDiv`, where is the tag with this ID in your HTML code ? And you can't use ID to loop elements, you'll have to use `getElementsByClassName()` or `getElementsByTagName` ...

Comment: iam using the id in the first line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Id 's` is unique.

If you use `jQuery`, then .You can use  same `class` for all divs.  `$('.className').hide();`

If you want solution in javascript

There's `getElementsByClassName` in some browsers, but it's not as widely supported as getElementById.   [**SEE HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560764/javascript-hide-elements-by-class-name)

otherwise  you can use different ids for diifferent divs then hide using ids

Answer (score 0):

ID should be a unique value. However, to group divs together you can use the same class name. Here's an example.

```
<div id="name" class="myClass">...</div>
<div id="address" class="myClass">...</div>
<div id="email" class="myOtherClass">...</div>
```

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) allows you to hide multiple elements that have the same class name like so

```
$(".myClass").hide();
```

which will hide `name` and `address` divs but not the `email` one. `.show();` makes them visible again.

Depending on what you intend to do, though, you can place everything you want to hide inside a div, and simply hide that div.

Answer (score 0):

Try with "**[querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)**"

```js
function hideShowDiv(){
  const samedivid = document.querySelectorAll("#samedivid");

for(let i=0;i<samedivid.length;i++){
 const styles = window.getComputedStyle(samedivid[i]);
    
    if(styles.visibility=='visible'){
    samedivid[i].style.visibility='hidden';
    }else{
    samedivid[i].style.visibility='visible';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body { 
  text-align: center;
}

#divTohide{
  visibility:visible;
}

.hidebtn{
  width:120px;
  height:40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="samedivid">
  <h1>Hi, This is the 1st DIV</h1>
</div>
<div id="samedivid">
  <h1>Hi, This is the 2nd DIV</h1>
</div>
<div id="samedivid">
  <h1>Hi, This is the 3rd DIV</h1>
</div>
 
<button class="hidebtn" onclick="hideShowDiv()">
  <b>hide/show</b>
</button>
```