# Handling HTML tags in XSL

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xslt

Before I explain the problem I'm facing, I probably need to explain the problem I wanted to solve in the first place. :)

I have an XML that will be formatted with XSL. This XML contains HTML tags in CDATA, for example:-

```
<doc>
    <![CDATA[
        <b>Hello!</b>
    ]]>
</doc>
```

When XSL performs the transformation, the browser displays `<b>Hello!</b>` rather than rendering the word **Hello!** in bold. I inspected the source code, and it looks like this:-

```
<doc>
    &lt;b&gt;Hello!&lt;/b&gt;
</doc>
```

To solve this problem, I'm thinking of using JQuery to render the text as HTML, like this:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var obj = $(".content");
    alert("text: " + obj.text()); // to test if JQuery works
    obj.html(obj.text());
});
```

So, I tried adding the JQuery library into XSL, and after couple of attempts and reading about the problem with `<script>` tag, it seems like I need to add a dummy between the opening and closing `<script>` tag, like this:-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js">
    <xsl:comment/>
</script>
```

The rendered display shows 2 errors in Firebug:-

```
b.style is undefined
(function(a,b){function ci(a){return d...a:a+"px")}}),a.jQuery=a.$=d})(window);

$ is not defined
```

... and the javascript statements above doesn't work at all, not even the alert prompt.

I decided to downgrade JQuery from 1.5.2 to 1.3.2 to see if that fixes anything. Now, I'm getting this error from Firebug:-

```
K.style is undefined
(function(){var R=/((?:\((?:\([^()]+\)...,typeof K==="string"?K:K+"px")}})})();
```

The good news is I'm getting the alert prompt with JQuery 1.3.2. The bad news is `obj.html(obj.text());` doesn't do anything.

Just out of curiosity, I change `obj.html(obj.text());` to `obj.text("Just Testing: " + obj.text());`, which is a dumb test, but it works... I'm seeing `Just Testing:`  being inserted into the actual content.

How do I get `obj.html(obj.text());` to work here? Or a more general question is, how do I get the HTML tags from CData to render as HTML and not as text?

Thanks much.

**UPDATE**

I did another test... `obj.html("aaa");` doesn't work either. I'm starting to believe it has something to do with the XSL transformation that prevents JQuery from working properly. I'm still using 1.3.2 here.

Comment: XSL does not "render the display". It transforms an input into an output, which it sounds like you're then displaying in Firefox. If you're not outputting HTML, then Firefox won't display it as HTML. You don't need jQuery; you need to output HTML in the first place.

Comment: Before going further please look into this: Does your server escape the characters? Because what may wind up happening is that there is so much entity-escape-un-escape going on that when you print you THINK you have unescaped entities, but you don't. Look if the <b> tags are escaped as &lt;b&gt; because injecting that into .html will cause <b> to be printed

Comment: I think the CDATA causes the `<b>` tag to show up as `&amp;lt;b&amp;gt;`... I'm seeing that in the source code, and yes, I'm using Firefox. That's the reason I want the escaped characteres to render as HTML by using `obj.html(obj.text());`, but I'm unable to get that working.

Comment: @Dmitriy makes my point more explicitly. If you're transforming input using XSLT in the browser, then you need to be careful not to conflate two separate things: 1) the output of the XSLT transformation; 2) the rendering of that output by the browser. To see the actual output of the transformation: first select the text, then right-click and choose "View Selection Source".

Comment: @limc: _"This XML contains HTML tags in CDATA"_... ***that's your problem***. CDATA sections are just unparsed text. You shouldn't expect that it can be output as elements unless you parse them first.

Comment: Use the method here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912501/unescape-html-entities-in-javascript

Comment: Also note that your code has one additional level of encoding (your `&` is encoded as `&amp;`), so you'll need to run it through twice, like this: `htmlDecode(htmlDecode("&amp;lt;b&amp;gt;"))` => `<b>`

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation of the problem and easy solution. Also, a warning for a very bad practice that must be avoided by all means.

Comment: I posted my workaround solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After futzing around, I think I finally found a solution to my problem. I decided not to use JQuery because the Firebug errors really bug me.

I incorporated this `getElementsByClassName()` function from [How to getElementByClass instead of GetElementById with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933602/how-to-getelementbyclass-instead-of-getelementbyid-with-javscript) into my solution. I created my own JS called "xml.js":-

**xml.js**

```
function getElementsByClassName(node,classname) {
    if (node.getElementsByClassName) { // use native implementation if available
        return node.getElementsByClassName(classname);
    } 
    else {
        return (function getElementsByClass(searchClass,node) {
            if (node == null) {
                node = document;
            }
            var classElements = [],
            els = node.getElementsByTagName("*"),
            elsLen = els.length,
            pattern = new RegExp("(^|\\s)"+searchClass+"(\\s|$)"), i, j;

            for (i = 0, j = 0; i < elsLen; i++) {
                if ( pattern.test(els[i].className) ) {
                    classElements[j] = els[i];
                    j++;
                }
            }
            return classElements;
        })(classname, node);
    }
}

window.onload=function() {
    var elements = getElementsByClassName(document, "html");

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
         var e = elements[i];
         e.innerHTML = e.innerHTML.replace(/&lt;/g, "<").replace(/&gt;/g, ">");
    }
};
```

**XSL**

I added this JS reference in the XSL:-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="xml.js"><xsl:comment/></script>
```

I basically added `class="html"` on the tags that require HTML formatting, for example:-

```
<p class="html">
    <xsl:call-template name="getDoc" />
</p>
```

**XML**

My XML has bunch of markups:-

```
<doc>     
  <![CDATA[         
     <b>Hello!</b> this is a <i>test</i>. 
      Email me at <a href="mailto:cow@dung.com">Moo</a>.
    ]]> 
</doc>
```

The HTML within the CDATA seems to get rendered properly in the browser.

**UPDATE**

Just a side note, I also tried removing CDATA and escape < and >:-

```
<doc>     
     &lt;b&gt;Hello!&lt;/b&gt; this is a &lt;i&gt;test&lt;/i&gt;. 
      Email me at &lt;a href="mailto:cow@dung.com"&gt;Moo&lt;/a&gt;.
</doc>
```

Then, I do the following:-

```
<xsl:value-of select="..." disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```

... and here's the result:-

- IE 8: works, rendered correctly.
- Chrome 9: works, rendered correctly
- Safari 5:  works, rendered correctly
- Firefox 4: does not work - shows up  tag instead of bolded word.

It seems like every browser is handling the rendering differently... pretty disappointed with FF4... bah.

At least for now, I'll stick with the javascript solution until I find a better one.

Answer (score 3):

**Instead of** :

```
<doc>     
  <![CDATA[         
     <b>Hello!</b>     
    ]]> 
</doc>
```

**Use**:

```
<doc>     
  <b>Hello!</b>     
 </doc>
```

**Putting markup inside a CDATA section is effectively destroying this markup** and converting it just to a string -- this is decreasing its dimension from 2 to 1.

**Very bad practice that should ve avoided!**

Comment: I understand the limitation in placing HTML tags in CDATA. However, there are too many HTML markups in XML file where the formats need to be preserved in the rendered output. With CDATA, I can easily use XSL to grab the entire content under `<doc>` whereas if I don't use CDATA, correct me if I'm wrong here, I believe I need to manually grab all the markups (if exists) under `<doc>` and place them in the right order during the XSL transformation. Granted, I have limited knowledge on XSL, so I may not be thinking it right too. Thanks much.

Comment: @limc: It will be better if you provide an example that proves your point. I don't thing there is a single example where destroying markup can be justified. Enclosing in CDATA may be needed only if the contents is not a well-formed XML fragment -- for example weird ASP or any other language that uses angle brackets but is not XML.

Comment: I'm generating a Jersey extended WADL. To do so, it grabs the Javadoc from the Resource classes generated using Doclet and merges into the original WADL. The Javadoc contains HTML markups, such as, `<a>`, `<p>`, `<ul>`, `<li>`, and so on. I would like them to be rendered as HTML in the generated WADL. Right now, if I don't wrap them using CDATA, these tags seem to go missing, and I think that makes sense because I believe I need to manually grab these tags and arrange them in the right order in the output, which seems like a lot of work. I figure the easier solution is to place them in CDATA.

Comment: I posted my workaround solution below. It seems to work well right now.

Comment: @limc: this is a crutch -- the correct solution is never to destroy markup. You may not understand this right now, but there will come the time when you will. Just bear in mind...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getting the text from obj first into a variable and then using the variable?

```
var objText = obj.text();
obj.html(objText);
```

Just a quick suggestion, just thought I would ask.

Comment: Also, check what is coming from the server.  You may want to look into the StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript(String string) method.