# css hide div if div has no child with class

Tags: css

Is it possible to hide a div with css if the div has no child div's with a specific class name?

```
<div class="parent">
 This div must be hidden
</div>

<div class="parent">
 This div must be visible
 <div class="child">
 child div
 </div>
</div>
```

If it's not possible with CSS, maybe with javascript or jQuery?

Comment: No, the child div would also be hidden. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I don't think you can do this in CSS alone. However, you can mange to do it with JavaScript.

Comment: looking for something like 
'if ( .parent AND .parent has .child ) hide this.parent ( not the other parent ) if that makes it more clear for you Drewid. preferably done in css or even add a class name if .parent has or does not has a child if that's gets you anywhere?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with just CSS, but it is definitely possible with Javascript.

You have to
 - find all divs with class `parent`
 - find all those with a child div with class `child`
 - if there is no such child, set `style.display = none`

Now, with **pure javascript** this can be a bit complicated. You can use the `getElementsByClassName` from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933602/how-to-getelementbyclass-instead-of-getelementbyid-with-javascript#answer-1933623) and then apply the above logic:

```
//getElementsByClassName from @CMS's answer to the linked question
var parentDivs = getElementsByClassName(document, "parent"); 
for(var i=0; i<parentDivs.length; i++)
{
    var children = getElementsByClassName(parentDivs[i], "child");
    if(!children || children.length == 0)
    {
        parentDivs[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

With [**jQuery**](http://jquery.com/), this is lot more simple:

```
$(".parent").each(function()
{
    if($(this).children(".child").length == 0)
    {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Live Example: http://jsfiddle.net/nivas/JWa9r/

Comment: thnx. I've done some more research and also tried to do it in another way ( by hiding all parent items and then showing only the parents who have a child ) but i must conclude that you cannot use a css selector to select a parent item. you can only select the element itself or decedents.

Answer (score 33):

Since of CSS3 you can use the :empty selector. This method is widely supported by all modern browsers and is much faster than it's javascript alternative.

Comment: But `:empty` fails, if inside `.parent` is any text (including spaces or line breaks).

Comment: @codename- it's not a failure of the empty selector because an element with even whitespace content is not empty.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is really fast. And it also works for elements containing sub-elements with text, if these are set to `display:none;` via CSS dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

With the new `:has()` selector in CSS you could do this:

```
.parent {
  display: none;
}

.parent:has(.child) {
  display: block;
}
```

Note that as of writing it doesn't yet work in Firefox without enabling a flag

Answer (score 1):

If anyone's still exploring a CSS-only approach, consider this.

**Note: This code directly checks if the parent element has any immediate children.**

```
.parent:not(:has(:first-child)) {
    display: none;
}
```