# Show/hide rows based on class in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Imagine I have a table of data in HTML and each of the rows have, say, one of three possible classes: RowA, RowB, and RowC; which represent the information in the rows. (For example, Small, Medium, and Large cars).

Above the table, I have 3 checkboxes: "Show Small Cars", "Show Medium Cars", "Show Large Cars".

If the user deselects "Show Small Cars", then the rows containing small cars should disappear.

This is how I would do it:

```
function showHideRows(classToShowOrHide, checkBoxSender)
{
  var tableObj = document.getElementById("myDataTable");

  for (i = 0; i < tableObj.childNodes.length; i++)
    if (tableObj.childNodes[i].className == classToShowOrHide)
      tableObj.childNodes[i].style.display = checkBoxSender.checked ? "visible" : "none";
}
```

Is there a better way? For example, can I modify the css class using javascript to include/exclude a `display: none`?

I'm not using jQuery.

Comment: Even though you're not using jQuery, you might want to look into how jQuery would do it, and see if you can just lift those few functions out of it.

Comment: I believe this will fail if the cell has more than one class.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933602/how-to-getelementbyclass-instead-of-getelementbyid-with-javascript

Specifically the post by CMS should help you.

Comment: @kingjiv The `<tr>` will only have one class, and this function will be used on only one page, ever :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you define your markup/styles as this:

```
<table class="showSmallCars showMediumCars">
  <tr class="smallCar">...<tr>
  <tr class="mediumCar">...<tr>
</table>

CSS:
table tr { display:none; }
table.showSmallCars tr.smallCar { display:table-row; }
table.showMediumCars tr.mediumCar { display:table-row; }
```

then it is enough for you to modify class attribute on table to present records of groups you need:
Thus `<table class="showSmallCars showMediumCars">` will show smalls an mediums
and `<table class="showSmallCars showMediumCars showLargeCars">` will show all of them.

And no need to scan all rows in script.

Comment: Beat me by 53 seconds! We've pretty much posted the same technique - one difference is that my version shows all rows by default, while this version shows none. This has nicer handling of multiple options, though. Nice job!

Comment: Oh hey, that's pretty clever! Thanks for that!

Comment: A nice tweak would be to use compound selectors:

`table.showSmallCars tr.smallCar, table.showMediumCars tr.mediumCar, table.showLargeCars tr.largeCar { display:table-row; }`

Comment: Yes, that's how I implemented it ;)

Answer (score 3):

jQuery is a cleaner way to do it; go to http://www.jquery.com and follow the instructions there to start using it, then your function becaomse

```
function showHideRows(classToShowOrHide, checkBoxSender)
{
    $('.' + classToShowOrHide, '#myDataTable').each(function(){
        $(this).css('display', ((checkBoxSender.checked) ? 'visible' : 'none'));
    });
}
```

---

If you want to do it in vanilla JS, something like this should be about right. Probably a gremlin in the following code somewhere, I don't do much vanilla JS any more :) jQuery is *that* good.

```
window.onload=function(){
    if (document.getElementsByClassName == undefined) {
        document.getElementsByClassName = function(className)
        {
            var hasClassName = new RegExp("(?:^|\\s)" + className + "(?:$|\\s)");
            var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
            var results = [];

            var element;
            for (var i = 0; (element = allElements[i]) != null; i++) {
                var elementClass = element.className;
                if (elementClass && elementClass.indexOf(className) != -1 && hasClassName.test(elementClass))
                    results.push(element);
            }

            return results;
        }
    }
}

function showHideRows(classToShowOrHide, checkBoxSender)
{
      for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName(classToShowOrHide); i++)
          document.getElementsByClassName(classToShowOrHide)[i].style.display = checkBoxSender.checked ? "visible" : "none";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Really, the basics of showing and hiding rows can be done very cleanly in CSS. Javascript is only required to tell the surrounding table what type it should show - and that's just a matter of setting a class name.

If this is your HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Type</td>
            <td>Price</td>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="rowA">
                <td>Falcon</td>
                <td>Large</td>
                <td>$160.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="rowA">
                <td>Commodore</td>
                <td>Large</td>
                <td>$160.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="rowB">
                <td>Camry</td>
                <td>Medium</td>
                <td>$110.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="rowB">
                <td>Lancer</td>
                <td>Medium</td>
                <td>$105.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="rowC">
                <td>Prius</td>
                <td>Small</td>
                <td>$75.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="rowC">
                <td>Civic</td>
                <td>Small</td>
                <td>$80.00</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Use this CSS:

```
/* The rows to show */

table.showTypeA .rowA,
table.showTypeB .rowB,
table.showTypeC .rowC {
  display: table-row;  
} 

/* Then, hide the other types */

table.showTypeA .rowB,
table.showTypeA .rowC,
table.showTypeB .rowA,
table.showTypeB .rowC,
table.showTypeC .rowA,
table.showTypeC .rowB {
    display: none; 
}
```

All you need to do with javascript is set a class on the table of 'showTypeA', 'showTypeB', 'showTypeC', and the browser will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked for JavaScript, but you could do it failry easy with jQuery.

Like:
http://jsfiddle.net/XJRVt/17/

You would proberbly also need to do a check on page load :)

Comment: Thanks, I have done this in jQuery in the past and I know it's very simple, but this project has to be jQuery-free unfortunately.