# Selecting tags, replacing values (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Before today I have never before used JavaScript so I'm trying to learn as I go here.

On a webpage I want to select all html input tags with the class "exampleClass" and I want to replace the value. Can anyone show me a good/quick code snippet on how to do this or point me in the right direction to another thread or tutorial?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to post the relevant HTML so those of us that don't generalize (IE: selector engines) can map out a solution. You can use `getElementsByTagName`, but there's an opportunity for an easier solution depending on your markup.

Comment: the markup is just a series of input tags that share a class, i.e.:
<input id="randomid" class="exampleClass" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Plain Javascript

In plain javascript (no jQuery-like framework), you could do it like this:

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName('exampleClass');

for (var i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; i++) {
    list[i].value = "foo";
}
```

But, `getElementsByClassName()` isn't supported in older versions of IE (not until IE9).  If you want to make the plain JS version work with older browsers, then you have to get a substitute for `getElementsByClassName()` for use when it isn't supported.  There are many implementations which you can find with Google.  Here's one of them: http://robertnyman.com/2008/05/27/the-ultimate-getelementsbyclassname-anno-2008/.

### jQuery

Frameworks like jQuery are very, very useful for this kind of operation and they have better cross-browser and old-browser support.  In jQuery, this operation would work pretty much everywhere and be just this one line.

```
$(".exampleClass").val("foo");
```

### Sizzle

If you want good cross-browser support, but want something lighter weight than jQuery, you can use just the Sizzle selector library (which is what is used inside of jQuery) in which case the code would be this:

```
var list = Sizzle('.exampleClass');

for (var i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; i++) {
    list[i].value = "foo";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is trivial if you use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/):

```
$('input.exampleClass').val('New Value');
```

or if no IE7 support is required [querySelectAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.querySelectorAll)

```
elementList = document.querySelectorAll('input.exampleClass');
for(var i = 0; i < elementList.lenght; i++) {
    elementList[i].value = "New Value";
}
```

or filter all input tags with [**getElementsBytagName**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName):

```
var element,
  elementList = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i = 0; i < elementList.lenght; i++) {
    element = elementList[i];
    if(element.className == "exampleClass") {
         element.value = "New Value";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! And can you very briefly explain what the $ stands for in javascript/jquery?

Comment: $ in javascript in general is just a legitimate variable name. However, many libraries, such as jQuery, assign it to their core function/object.

Answer (score 1):

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');

for ( var x = 0, len = elements.length; x < len; x += 1 )
{
    elements[x].value = 'your value here';
}
```

If you want a better hint of how it works, be sure to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933602/how-to-getelementbyclass-instead-of-getelementbyid-with-javascript/1933623#1933623).

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you are new to JavaScript then jQuery would be an easy to start because it has very [powerful selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) that are relatively easy to write vs. plain JavaScript. A jQuery example would look like this:

Try this:

```
<!-- Uses jQuery library hosted by Google -->
<script language="javascript" scr="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

$('.exampleClass').val('replacedValue');
```

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you were using jQuery.

Comment: jQuery is javascript. The OP didn't prohibit libraries.

Comment: How would you iterate through the set if you used the jquery selector?

Comment: The jquery selector automatically selects the elements based on the rules you provide it.  `$('.exampleClass')` selects all elements with `class = 'exampleClass'`.

Comment: `$('li')` would select all list elements and `$('#parent li')` would select all list elements nested within an element with `id="parent"`

Comment: So if I used:
var Set = $('.exampleClass');
I could then iterate through 'Set' with a for loop?

Comment: @Marshal: jQuery always acts on an array of objects that reference the elements you've indicated. Built-in iteration.

Comment: @Marshal even better you can connect functions to act on your selected elements like `$('.exampleClass').each (function() { alert( this.val()); });`

Answer (score 0):

```
var exClass = document.getElementsByClassName('exampleClass');

for(var i = 0; i < exClass.length; i++) {
    exClass[i].value = "new Value";
}
```

Fiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/4aWje/

Comment: You should know better than to use `for...in` to iterate over an array, amigo. -1 https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Parameters

Comment: This is perfect! this very easily allowed me to iterate through the set! thank you!

Comment: @Marshal -- no problem ^_^ happy to help

Comment: @Marshal, be aware that this is supported in IE9 and greater: http://caniuse.com/#search=getElementsByClassName

Comment: @Matt Ball: In this case, it's no harm. `for..in` will get the job done. The sin comes when order matters. Here it doesn't. The yellow box mid-way down your referenced page tells all.

Comment: @Jonathan it can be worse than that: _"...it will return all enumerable properties, including those with non–integer names and those that are inherited"_

Comment: @Matt Ball: ah, yes. Thanks. BTW, he fixed the answer.

Comment: @Jonathan especially if it's not just a vanilla array: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/m4BPR/. ...yes, I removed my downvote a while ago