# How to get the html of CLASS using jQuery or JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get the html text of CLASS and use another function to change the html text?

For example, there are lot of tags (td) using the same class. But the inner html of that class will be changed after the function called.

HTML

```
<table>
 <tr><td class="number">1</td></tr>
 <tr><td class="number">2</td></tr>
 <tr><td class="number">3</td></tr>
 <tr><td class="number">4</td></tr>
 <tr><td class="number">5</td></tr>
</table>
```

jQuery / JS

```
function ChangeNumber(){
 var cusid_ele = document.getElementsByClassName('number');
 for (var i = 0; i < cusid_ele.length; ++i) {
  var item = cusid_ele[i];
  item.innerHTML = number(item.innerHTML);
 }
}

function number(n){
 if(n == 1)
  return "one";
 else if(n == 2)
  return "two";
 else if(n == 3)
  return "three";
 else if(n == 4)
  return "four";
 else if(n == 5)
  return "five";
}

window.onload = function(){ ChangeNumber() };
```

I don't know if my codes are incorrect. Yes, it is not working, so I need help. I just refer to this URL: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15560734/2903208

Could anyone try this? And if success, well that's great!

I want the output that will be:

```
one
two
three
four
five
```

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance! ^_^

Comment: you just forgot to add variable name near var

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.number').each(function({ // added '
        alert($(this).text()); // added (
    });
});
```

EDIT:
Change the HTML to

```
<table>
 <tr><td class="number" title="one">1</td></tr>
 <tr><td class="number" title="two">2</td></tr>
 <tr><td class="number" title="three">3</td></tr>
 <tr><td class="number" title="four">4</td></tr>
 <tr><td class="number" title="five">5</td></tr>
</table>
```

and modify the above function to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.number).each(function({
        alert($this).attr('title'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. I am newbie in jQuery. Thanks again.

Comment: simply add the above script in your JS file... Dont forget to add jquery refernce on your page

Answer (score 2):

```
var map = {
    1: 'one',
    2: 'two',
    3: 'three',
    4: 'four',
    5: 'five',
    ........
}

$('table .number').text(function(_,txt) {
    return map[parseInt($.trim(txt), 10)];
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/CxNw6/)

Answer (score 1):

change your line below

FROM THIS

```
    var  = document.getElementsByClassName('number');
```

TO

```
    var cusid_ele = document.getElementsByClassName('number');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this by a `class selector` .

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.number').each(function({
        var strhtml = $(this).text();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrap your function to `onload` event. But the `onload` event is a standard event in the DOM, which occurs later, when all content (e.g. images) also has been loaded.

You can use `.ready` event(The ready event occurs after the HTML document has been loaded).

Try this :

HTML-

```
<table>
 <tr><td class="number">1</td></tr>
 <tr><td class="number">2</td></tr>
 <tr><td class="number">3</td></tr>
 <tr><td class="number">4</td></tr>
 <tr><td class="number">5</td></tr>
</table>
```

Script code-

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    ChangeNumber();
});


function ChangeNumber(){
 var cusid_ele = document.getElementsByClassName('number');        
 for (var i = 0; i < cusid_ele.length; ++i) {
  var item = cusid_ele[i];
  item.innerHTML = number(item.innerHTML);
 }
}

function number(n){
 if(n == 1)
  return "one";
 else if(n == 2)
  return "two";
 else if(n == 3)
  return "three";
 else if(n == 4)
  return "four";
 else if(n == 5)
  return "five";
}
```

[Try is jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZWtEh/1/)