# Get complete element by class name

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to getElementByClass instead of GetElementById with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933602/how-to-getelementbyclass-instead-of-getelementbyid-with-javascript)
>   [How to Get Element By Class in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808808/how-to-get-element-by-class-in-javascript)

I need to get the complete tag by class. Is it possible to do in javascript without any cross browser issues.

For eg., if the element is,

`<img src="hello.jpg" class="myclass" />`

Then i need to get,

`<img src="hello.jpg" class="myclass" />` by using class name. Any solution or suggestion on this would be greatly appreciated.

**Note:** Please note that, i don't wnt to use any JavaScript library.

Comment: No I'm not using any JavaScript library.

Comment: What operation do you plan to do after getting the whole element.

Comment: What is a "complete" element? There's dozens, hundreds, possibly thousands of questions asking this; have those not worked for you?

Comment: @JaredFarrish The element with the same class will not occur more thn once

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("myclass")`
should return a HTMLCollection
you get an array of hte html elements ->
`document.getElementsByClassName("myclass")[0]` would give you what you want

Comment: @MarcB - Isn't `document.getElementsByClassName()` not supported in some earlier but somehow still "required" browsers? In that case, `document.querySelector()` would also be relevant.

Comment: Udhay, that is not per se a *class*; use an `id` and then `document.getElementById('id')`. Succinct and *correct*. `class` should only be used if one or more elements are being grouped, `id` for non-serial elements (and there should only be one `id` value per page).

Comment: http://forums.devshed.com/javascript-development-115/javascript-get-all-elements-of-class-abc-24349.html this will solve it

Answer (score 0):

Find your element using `document.getElementsByClassName('myclass')`. This returns an array, so you can check if it's empty and retrieve its first element via `[0]`.

After that, you can get the full tag as string using its `outerHTML` property.