# Is it possible to populate the values of all elements of a class?

Tags: javascript, forms

What I want to achieve is populating many form fields with the same value. I can do it for an element that has an id:

```
function selectDateAndArendeSearch(year, month, day, field, number, numberfield) {
    var m = parseInt(month)+1;

    if(m<10)
        month="0"+m;
    else
        month=m;
    if(day.length==1)
        day="0"+day;

    document.actionForm.all(field).value = year+"-"+month+"-"+day;
    document.actionForm.all(numberfield).value = number;
    document.getElementById('popupF').style.display = 'none';
}
```

But how do I do it for many elements i.e. a class?

Comment: I use jQuery as my everyday js companion. In jquery you use each()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('myclassname').value = 'New Value';
```

Comment: There is no such function, it's `getElementsByClassName` and it returns an array, which you have to iterate over.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (el in document.getElementsByClassName('myclassname')) {
    el.value = "New Value";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `getElementsByClassName` is perfect for the mayority of modern browsers.
However if you need compatibility with old browsers, it might not be native. In this case, have a look to CMS's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1933623/1032370), who provides a portable function for this task.

For **compatibility** see the following **[working draft](http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname)**

Comment: It¨s OK if it works with IE 5+. My requirement is down to IE 6 only is OK.

Comment: @Nick Rosencrantz Then I strongly suggest you to use the portable method: see my edit for a link to a working draft compatibility. It's native only in IE9.