# Get clicked class index javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 3 divs with class: wpEdit and onClick: alertName()

```
<div class="wpEdit" onClick="alertName()">Bruce Lee</div>
<div class="wpEdit" onClick="alertName()">Jackie Chan</div>
<div class="wpEdit" onClick="alertName()">Jet li</div>
```

When clicked i want to know the Index of class wpEdit of the clicked Div:

```
function alertName(){
    //Something like this
    var classIndex = this.className.index; // This obviously dosnt work
    alert(classIndex); 
}
```

when clicked on  Bruce Lee it should alert : 0
when clicked on  Jackie Chan it should alert : 1
when clicked on  Jet Li it should alert : 2

I need to know which instance of class="wpEdit" is clicked on

Comment: i want to do it by pure js, but if not jQuery is cool

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
function clickedClassHandler(name,callback) {

    // apply click handler to all elements with matching className
    var allElements = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");

    for(var x = 0, len = allElements.length; x < len; x++) {
        if(allElements[x].className == name) {
            allElements[x].onclick = handleClick;
        }
    }

    function handleClick() {
        var elmParent = this.parentNode;
        var parentChilds = elmParent.childNodes;
        var index = 0;

        for(var x = 0; x < parentChilds.length; x++) {
            if(parentChilds[x] == this) {
                break;
            }

            if(parentChilds[x].className == name) {
                index++;
            }
        }

        callback.call(this,index);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
clickedClassHandler("wpEdit",function(index){
    // do something with the index
    alert(index);

    // 'this' refers to the element 
    // so you could do something with the element itself
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';
});
```

Comment: WoW I was looking for a way to find the current index in a set of elements through vanilla JS. I stumbled upon http://stackoverflow.com/a/1933609/1606729 but I wouldn't have written such a good answer

Comment: .. and I just found out what Vanilla JS is

Comment: I was really wondering what was not "vanilla" in your example ^^ Glad he accepted your answer in the end!

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you might want to address in your code is the inline HTML binding.

You could use `document.addEventListener` on each element, or rely on [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate).

The widely most used implementation of event delegation comes with jQuery. If you're already using jQuery, this is the way to go!

Alternatively I've also my own little [`delegate` utility](https://github.com/brunoscopelliti/delegate).

```
const delegate = (fn, selector) => {
  return function handler(event) {
    const matchingEl = matches(event.target, selector, this);
    if(matchingEl != null){
      fn.call(matchingEl, event);
    }
  };
};

const matches = (target, selector, boundElement) => {
  if (target === boundElement){
    return null;
  }
  if (target.matches(selector)){
    return target;
  }
  if (target.parentNode){
    return matches(target.parentNode, selector, boundElement);
  }
  return null;
};
```

This is how you would register the event listener.

```
document.getElementById('#parent')
  .addEventListener('click', delegate(handler, '.wpEdit'));
```

And this is how you could get the index of the element that generated the event.

```
const handler = (event) => {
  console.log(Array.prototype.indexOf.call(event.currentTarget.children, event.target));
}
```

Live demo:

```js
const delegate = (fn, selector) => {
  return function handler(event) {
    const matchingEl = matches(event.target, selector, this);
    if (matchingEl != null) {
      fn.call(matchingEl, event);
    }
  };
};

const matches = (target, selector, boundElement) => {
  if (target === boundElement) {
    return null;
  }
  if (target.matches(selector)) {
    return target;
  }
  if (target.parentNode) {
    return matches(target.parentNode, selector, boundElement);
  }
  return null;
};

const handler = (event) => {
  console.log(Array.prototype.indexOf.call(event.currentTarget.children, event.target));
}

document.getElementById('parent')
  .addEventListener('click', delegate(handler, '.wpEdit'));
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="wpEdit">Bruce Lee</div>
  <div class="wpEdit">Jackie Chan</div>
  <div class="wpEdit">Jet li</div>
</div>
```

Comment: jQuery would be the easiest way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the index of the div's based on your class wpEdit you can do like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="wpEdit">Bruce Lee</div>
<div class="wpEdit">Jackie Chan</div>
<div class="other">Other</div>
<div class="wpEdit">Jet li</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".wpEdit").bind("click", function(){
    var divs = $(".wpEdit");
    var curIdx = divs.index($(this));

    alert(curIdx);
});
```

Live example : http://jsfiddle.net/pJwzc/

More information on the index function of jQuery : http://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: No one mentionned explicitely "I want to do this in pure javascript" either. I don't see the problem in giving a working answer, I don't know how to do this in pure javascript but I'm searching.

Comment: since i think he only used javascript tag

Comment: He might have only used javascript tags because he doesn't even know about jQuery. I explained I'm using jQuery and gave a link to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Using vanilla javascript, this one works for me:

```
var wpEdits = document.querySelectorAll(".wpEdit");

for (let i = 0; i < wpEdits.length; i++)
  wpEdits[i].addEventListener("click", showID);

function showID(evt) {
  for (let i = 0; i < wpEdits.length; i++)
    if(wpEdits[i] == evt.target)    
      alert(i);
}
```

May not be the best solution though as I am still new to js.

**Since I am very new to JS, take the following explanation with a grain of salt:**

(Line-1) 
This is similar to `var wpEdits = document.getElementsByClassName("wpEdit");`. It will assign all instances of `class="wpEdit"` from the html file to the `wpEdits` variable.

(Line-3 and Line-4)
This two lines will cause any click on the `class="wpEdit"` to call function `showID()` defined below.

(Line-6 and Line-10)
When a click event happens, the browser will pass the unique properties of the item being clicked to the `evt` variable. This then is used in the for loop to compare against all available instances incrementally. The `evt.target` is used to get to the actual target. Once a match is found, it will alert the user.

To avoid wasting CPU time, running a `break;` is recommended to exit the loop soon after the match is found.

Comment: Hi Afdhal, and welcome to Stack Overflow!  Can you provide a brief explanation of how/why this works, beyond just providing the code?  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcome @MaxvonHippel !

Forgive me for not explaining the code. I am very new to JS and I don't think I am qualified to explain it as I worry it might confuse others. I will do my best to explain it this time.

Answer (score 0):

I could not understand, why people add new functions in previous answers, so...

```
const wpEdit = document.getElementsByClassName('wpEdit');
for(let i = 0; i < wpEdit.length; i++){
  wpEdit[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
    alert(i);
  });
}
```

I just added 'click' event, using the loop. And [i] already is the current clicked class index...

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/g5eL0z7c/)