# Show hidden rows in table with dropdown

Tags: javascript, select, drop-down-menu, html-table, hidden

I have something that seems fairly simple but I'm stumped. I want a dropdown within a table that affects how many table rows are shown. By default, only 2 rows are shown. By selecting 4 in the dropdown, 4 rows should be shown. I am only seeing one of the hidden rows show up, and I've tried to wrap the 2 rows in a hidden div as well, no luck. Ideas?

```
  <table border="1">
          <tr>
            <td class="noBG" colspan="3">
              <select id="displayText" onchange="javascript:toggle();">
                <option>2</option>
                <option>4</option>
              </select>Items
            </td>
          </tr>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Dates</th>
              <th>Time</th>
              <th>Person</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
            <tr>
              <td>12/3</td>
              <td>12:45</td>
              <td>John Doe</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>12/4</td>
              <td>12:45</td>
              <td>James Doe</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="toggleText" style="display: none">
              <td>12/4</td>
              <td>12:45</td>
              <td>Janey Doe</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="toggleText" style="display: none">
              <td>12/4</td>
              <td>12:45</td>
              <td>Janey Doe</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <script language="javascript"> 
        function toggle() {
            var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText");
            if(ele.style.display == "block") {
                    ele.style.display = "none"; 
            }
            else {
                ele.style.display = "block";
            }
        } 
        </script>
        ​
```

Comment: getElementById is only going to get one element

Comment: Your question is very similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933602/how-to-getelementbyclass-instead-of-getelementbyid-with-javascript

Comment: Don't use the attribute `id` to identify a group of elements.  Ids are supposed to be unique and not duplicated.

Comment: The problem at all is not the id, but the usage of the display attribute (see my answer below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `display: block;` doesn't work as the table rows will then displayed not in the right way. But you can toggle the visibility by adding and removing a class, which is defined with `display: none;`. So you must not switch `display: none/block;`, but the class.

This works (incl. jQuery): http://jsfiddle.net/Yuvvc/1/

You can use following code for JS function:

```
function toggle() {
    $.each($('tr[name=toggleText]'), function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("hiddenRow", $(this).attr('class') != "hiddenRow");
    });
}
```

With the second parameter (bool) for `.toggleClass` you can add and remove the class.

*EDIT*

Here a non-jQuery version:

```
function toggle() {
    var rows = document.getElementsByName("toggleText");
    for(var i=0; i<rows.length; i++)
    {
        rows[i].className = (rows[i].className == "hiddenRow") ? "" : "hiddenRow";
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Works perfectly, thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Change all `<tr id="toggleText"` to `<tr name="toggleText"`, and then change the toggle function to the following:

```
function toggle() {
    var ele = document.getElementsByName("toggleText");
    for (var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
        if (ele[i].style.display == "block") { 
            ele[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        else {
            ele[i].style.display = "block";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle the hidden rows by giving each row an id like this:

```
<table class="table">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td onclick="toggle1(@item.ID)" colspan="3">

            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)

        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="hidden" id="bluh_@item.ID">


        <td>

            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Code)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Position)
        </td>
    </tr>

}
```

then use JavaScript to Hide and Show the Children Rows

```
<script>
    function toggle1(something) {
        $("#bluh_"+something).toggleClass('hidden');
    }
</script>
```