# How to apply CSS style to all elements with same ID using one button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My idea was to create a button to hide/show all hidden text (Hide by highlighting the text in black, show by making the background color of the text transparent). But the codes, as shown below, only works for the 1st element with the given ID ("p2").

Javascript:

```
function change()
{
    var test = document.getElementById("button1");
    if (test.value=="Hide Spoiler") 
    {  
        test.value = "Open Spoiler"; 
        document.getElementById("p2").style.backgroundColor="black";  
    }
    else  
    {  
        test.value = "Hide Spoiler"; 
        document.getElementById("p2").style.color="black";
        document.getElementById("p2").style.backgroundColor="transparent";  
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<input onclick="change()" type="button" value="Open Curtain" id="button1"></input>
<br>
<span id="p2">Hidden text</span> Test for more <span id="p2">Hidden text</span> test again. <span id="p2">Hidden text</span>
```

How would I make all the elements with similar ID to change its CSS style using only 1 button? Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't have multiple elements with the same `id`, an `id` is supposed to be unique.

Comment: `id` should be unique, you need to add a specific class to your `span` elements

Comment: The question is tagged with `[jquery]`... are you using it?

Comment: Try this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/RYh7U/65/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is only every going to update one element, because `getElementById` will only ever return one element (because, as we've said, `id` is supposed to be unique).  If you need to mark multiple elements as related use a `class` instead. [Here is a working example using `class`](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/Dn9cX/), JavaScript:

```
function change() {
    var test = document.getElementById("button1");
    var els = document.getElementsByClassName("p2");
    if (test.value == "Hide Spoiler") {
        test.value = "Open Spoiler";
        for (var i=0; i<els.length; i++) {
            els[i].style.backgroundColor = "black";
        }
    } else {
        test.value = "Hide Spoiler";
        for (var i=0; i<els.length; i++) {
            els[i].style.color = "black";
            els[i].style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<input onclick="change()" type="button" value="Hide Spoiler" id="button1"></input>
<br>
<span class="p2">Hidden text</span> Test for more <span class="p2">Hidden text</span> test again. <span class="p2">Hidden text</span>
```

If you need it to work in browsers too old for `getElementsByClassName`, try using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).  It makes this sort of thing lots easier

Comment: The question is tagged `[jquery]` so not sure if the OP is using it already, wants to use it, or just has no idea how to use it.

Comment: @Sparky With no evidence of jQuery use in the question, I just assumed the OP just used the tag because it was popular and related.

Comment: Relax... I'm not criticizing your answer, I'm criticizing the OP for potential tag-spam, while expanding upon your last sentence in the answer.

Comment: @Sparky It's OK, I'm relaxed, just explaining why I ignored the tag.

Comment: The reason why I tag jquery is because I allow anyone to use jquery for this question in case if jquery is more convenient than javascript. Thanks for the code. It works!!

Answer (score 0):

Use a `class` instead of an `id`. Then use `document.getElementsByClassName("p2")` which will return an array of the matching elements and loop over them.

Comment: I thought there was no direct way to get a Class in pure JS?

Comment: There's no direct way to get anything in an HTML document in pure JS. You need a DOM API for that and browsers will supply one. `getElementsByClassName` is well supported [except for IE 8 and earlier](http://caniuse.com/#search=getElementsByClassName).

Comment: Didn't know about that new spec. Thanks for mentioning it :)

Answer (score 0):

id is unique, so it's not valid to have multiple instances [http://www.tizag.com/cssT/cssid.php] - you could however use a class and then select all instance with $(".className") (assuming jQuery).
This answer [How to getElementByClass instead of GetElementById with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933602/how-to-getelementbyclass-instead-of-getelementbyid-with-javascript) contains a lot of helpful pointers

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, do not use the same id more than once on a single page.  Instead, use a class name or data attributes.  And since you marked your question with jQuery:

```
function change()
{
    var test = document.getElementById("button1");
    if (test.value=="Hide Spoiler") 
    {
        test.value = "Open Spoiler"; 
        $('.className').css('background-color','transparent');
    }
    else 
    {
        test.value = "Hide Spoiler"; 
        $('.className').css('background-color','transparent');
        $('.className').css('color','black');
    }
}
```

If you're going to use jQuery, I'd also recommend using the button's click event like such:

```
$('#button1').click(function() {
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I oppose the Same ID concept... But Try like below will be a answer to your question....

Fiddle Example : http://jsfiddle.net/RYh7U/65/

**CSS**

```
.mask
{
color : red;
}
```

**Javascript :**

```
function change()
{
 var elements = document.getElementById("p2").parentNode.getElementsByTagName("span");
    for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++)
      elements[i].className = "mask";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input onclick="change()" type="button" value="Open Curtain" id="button1"/>
<br/>
<span class="p2">Hidden text</span> Test for more <span class="p2">Hidden text</span> test again. <span class="p2">Hidden text</span>
```

then the jquery:

```
function change() {
    var test = document.getElementById("button1");
    if (test.value == "Hide Spoiler") {
        test.value = "Open Spoiler";
        $('.p2').css('background-color','black')

    }
    else {
        test.value = "Hide Spoiler";
        $('.p2').css('background-color', 'transparent')

    }
}
```

I've tested it