# How can i get elements by class instead of "GetElementById"?

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

So, this is the code:

```
<a id="link" href="https://url.com/">URL:</a>
<input id="value"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var link= document.getElementById('link');
    var input= document.getElementById('value');
    input.onchange=input.onkeyup= function() {
        link.search= 'extendurl/'+encodeURIComponent(input.value);
    };
</script>
```

this is working, but i need to use the class instead of the ID. I try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var link= document.getElementByClassName("link")[0];
    var input= document.getElementByClassName("value")[0];
    input.onchange=input.onkeyup= function() {
        link.search= 'extendurl/'+encodeURIComponent(input.value);
        link.firstChild.data= link.href;
    };
</script>

<a class="link" href="https://url.com/">URL:</a>
<input class="value"/>
```

i don't know why, but this isn't working.

Someone?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933602/how-to-getelementbyclass-instead-of-getelementbyid-with-javascript?rq=1

Comment: Please read the `Questions that may already have your answer` section when posting new questions.

Answer (score 7):

The precise name is important.

Change

```
getElementByClassName
```

to

```
getElementsByClassName
```

There's a `s` because there might be more than one element with a give class, contrary to elements with a specific id.

Comment: Don't forget to cast a close vote.

Comment: @RobW done. I'm amazed you find a duplicate for this one...

Comment: @dystroy This is a common typo, I just Googled for it: [`site:stackoverflow.com getElementByClassName`](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+getElementByClassName), and found this as the third result.

Answer (score 2):

There can be many elements with the exact same class names, so you have to adjust it for that

instead of

```
getElementByClassName
```

you have to do

```
getElementsbyClassName("someclass");
```

and it will return an array of all of them