# Only make certain images fluid

Tags: javascript

This code is from here http://unstoppablerobotninja.com/entry/fluid-images

It takes all the images from a page and makes them fluid. It works great and i am sure many of you know it already.

My question is how can i apply this code only to certain images on the page, either through an ID or through a CLASS. something like this:

```
<img alt="" src="fluid_image.png" id="makeitfuild"/>
```

I don't want all my pictures to be fluid but still i want to use the code to certain images.

Please help as i don't know what i need to modify in the code

```
    var imgSizer = {
     Config : {
          imgCache : []
          ,spacer : "/path/to/your/spacer.gif"
     }
     ,collate : function(aScope) {
          var isOldIE = (document.all && !window.opera && !window.XDomainRequest) ? 1 : 0;
          if (isOldIE && document.getElementsByTagName) {
               var c = imgSizer;
               var imgCache = c.Config.imgCache;
               var images = (aScope && aScope.length) ? aScope : document.getElementsByTagName("img");
               for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                    images.origWidth = images.offsetWidth;
                    images.origHeight = images.offsetHeight;
                    imgCache.push(images);
                    c.ieAlpha(images);
                    images.style.width = "100%";
               }
               if (imgCache.length) {
                    c.resize(function() {
                         for (var i = 0; i < imgCache.length; i++) {
                              var ratio = (imgCache.offsetWidth / imgCache.origWidth);
                              imgCache.style.height = (imgCache.origHeight * ratio) + "px";
                         }
                    });
               }
          }
     }
     ,ieAlpha : function(img) {
          var c = imgSizer;
          if (img.oldSrc) {
               img.src = img.oldSrc;
          }
          var src = img.src;
          img.style.width = img.offsetWidth + "px";
          img.style.height = img.offsetHeight + "px";
          img.style.filter = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='" + src + "', sizingMethod='scale')"
          img.oldSrc = src;
          img.src = c.Config.spacer;
     }
     // Ghettomodified version of Simon Willison's addLoadEvent() -- http://simonwillison.net/2004/May/26/addLoadEvent/
     ,resize : function(func) {
          var oldonresize = window.onresize;
          if (typeof window.onresize != 'function') {
               window.onresize = func;
          } else {
               window.onresize = function() {
                    if (oldonresize) {
                         oldonresize();
                    }
                    func();
               }
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to change the following line:

```
var images = (aScope && aScope.length) ? aScope : document.getElementsByTagName("img");
```

to something that will get your images by a class name.  There are a few ways to do that: you can use jQuery, in which case it simply becomes

```
var images = (aScope && aScope.length) ? aScope : $("#myClassName");
```

or, you can look up any of the questions about how to get elements simply by class using only javascript ([How to getElementByClass instead of GetElementById with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933602/how-to-getelementbyclass-instead-of-getelementbyid-with-javascript) and [How to Get Element By Class in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808808/how-to-get-element-by-class-in-javascript) both quickly jump to mind).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion,  i did the change in the code and the class to an image, but it still makes all images fuild, regardless if i apply the class or not.

Comment: Is there anything else i must change?

Comment: @RaduS I'm surprised you accepted my solution.  Based on your comments, it didn't seem it worked for you.  How did you solve your problem? (As much as I appreciate getting reputation, if the answer didn't work, you're not obligated to accept it.)