# Modify function to use html class instead of id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a resize image  function which takes as input the ID of an file input element and .onchange it takes the image in the form and outputs a resized canvas of the image. Now I have changed the form structure from a static form where I know the IDs to a dynamically generated form where I only know the class of the input.

`<input type="file" class"image" id="some database genererated id such as 857432">`

How to do I modify the function to notice when a file input element of class="image" is .onchange and then perform the resize function on that particular element?

```
function resizeImage(inputfile, outputcontainer, outputname) {
    document.getElementById(inputfile).onchange = function(e) {
    var file = e.target.files[0]
    var image = new Image(file);
    etc.....

    };
}
```

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933602/how-to-getelementbyclass-instead-of-getelementbyid-with-javascript)

Comment: did you try to use jquery? It would make it a lot easier becaues it provides a selector for class names $(".classname")

Comment: You can try something like
    `var element = document.getElementsByClassName()[0];
    element.onchange = function(e) { ... }`
Hope this help

Comment: In pure javascript, you can use _document.getElementsByClassName("inputfileclassname")[0]_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use like below

```
function resizeImage(inputfileClass, outputcontainer, outputname) {
    $('.' + inputfileClass).change = function(e) {
    var file = e.target.files[0]
    var image = new Image(file);
    etc.....

    };
}
```

Comment: `$('.' + inputfileClass).onchange = function(e) {` should be `$('.' + inputfileClass).change(function(e) {......});`

Comment: Thanks Jitendra and Arun, I was obviously overthinking this way too much :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function resizeImage(inputfile, outputcontainer, outputname) {
    $(".image").change  = function(e) {
    var file = e.target.files[0]
    var image = new Image(file);
    etc.....

    };
}
```