# Javascript get values of multiple text fields

Tags: javascript

I have a dynamic web page where the content may contain between 1 and 10 links, provided in text boxes, similar to the following:

```
<input size="50" id="link" value="http://Something.Something" type="text">
<input size="50" id="link" value="http://SomethingElse.Something" type="text">
```

I need javascript to be able to read all of the links, and be able to manipulate the data (store in array, output to screen, etc)

I know that I can read a single id using the following

```
var link = document.getElementById('link');
```

Which will return the first match - but, how can I do a loop or obtain all the values for all the links, bearing in mind that the number of links cannot be determined beforehand?

P.S. I have tried using getElementsByTagName('input') but there are more inputs on the page, which means it's getting more results than I'd like it to get.

Comment: Id must be unigue. You cant have multiple items with the same Id

Comment: if its possible for you add a common class to all the inputs where you will file links and then fetch all elements with that class name as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933602/how-to-getelementbyclass-instead-of-getelementbyid-with-javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make them all have names and search by name.

```
<input name="vrow" value="0" type="text"/>
<input name="vrow" value="0" type="text"/>
<input name="vrow" value="0" type="text"/>
<input name="vrow" value="0" type="text"/>
```

Then you can get it with:

```
var vrows = document.getElementsByName("vrow");
alert(vrows.length);
```

Comment: Thank you, I like and have used this solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Give them all a common class and access using **document.getElementsByClassName('class')**.

Answer (score 1):

IDs should be unique for each element. You could use `document.getElementsByClassName` or `document.querySelectorAll(".class");` and then use the class name (assuming relatively modern browser). Or use `document.getElementsByTagName()` and then iterate through the elements comparing with the class.

Answer (score 0):

Attach a jQuery lib and you will be able to do something like:

```
$('input[type=text]').each(function(i, val){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```