# Using JavaScript to show total of an order

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a table of items available for purchases which I am displaying on the site. I am using mysql to fetch all the items and display them in a table. Among others, the table contains this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="price" id="price'.$id.'">  //id is one part of MySQL query results
<input type="text" name="count_'.$id.'">
```

All this is displayed for around 200 items with ID being not completely in sequence (I found some JavaScript code that used `for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {}`, however, with my IDs not being in a sequence, this is not a good option for me).

I would like to display a total of an order using JavaScript and I am not experienced when it comes to JS. I would be very thankful for your advices.

Comment: Can you post whole table html here ?

Comment: Why would the order of IDs matter if you're calculating the total of all rows?

Comment: It is kind of messy and not comprehensible for english speakers, is it necessary?

Comment: No, not really. Two lines would be enough.

Comment: please clarify clearly. what you want `total no of item in order` or `total price of an order`. also does `$id` has the count of each item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You coul duse `jQuery`:

```
function orderTotal()
{
   var total=0;
   $('input[name="price"]').each(function(){
      var price = parseFloat($(this).val());
      var amount = parseFloat($('input[name="count_'+$(this).attr('name').substring(5)+'"]').val());
      total += price+amount;
   });
   return total;
}
```

Comment: Corrected the type of `price`and `amount`. But the reference to `count` is better this way beacuse it is more robust to possible changes in the HTML.

Comment: Removed the downvote because it will work (didnt test if it does), but the amount selector is still very messy, which isn't needed

Comment: I agree with your previous comment in that a `.next()` would be simplier, but it relies in that the next element to `price` is `count`... In my version, if the page style changes, the code keeps working.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. One more question before I try to get it to work - do I have to trigger this function after every change of input values?

Comment: Yes. This function reads the input values and rturns the total price. So, you need to trigger it every time you need a new total.

Comment: What type of event should I use? I already have a onKeyDown event to prevent from submitting the form when enter is pressed.

Comment: I used this solution, however, the JS does not seem to be working. Event the functions that were previously functional dont work now. Where could be the problem?

Comment: There must be a syntax error. Could you look at the Javascript console, Firebug or similar? (for example with Firefox, Chrome or Safari)

Comment: And: do you have the jquery script loaded in your page?

Comment: I do have a file jQuery.js that I use for displaying onMouseOver pictures of the products. Do you think this file contains everything that is needed?

Comment: Everytime I change some value it types: Uncaught ReferenceError: checkForEnter is not defined and same goes for the checkForEnter() function. Also: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } bp.....com/:106
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Comment: mmmm.... I think the error is `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } bp.....com`. Could you try to solve it? What browser are you using? Could I take a look to your webpage?

Comment: Is there a way to give you a link privately?

Comment: Send it in an email to my name (just the first word) followed by @amidasoft.com

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you wrap them in another element, lets use `div`. Add a class to that, lets say `moneyline`

```
<div class="moneyline">
    <input class="price" type="hidden" name="price" id="price'.$id.'">  //id is one part of MySQL query results
    <input class="quantity" type="text" name="count_'.$id.'">
</div>
```

Im going to give the example with jQuery, and some button to trigger it:

```
$('#someButton').on('click', function(){
    var total = 0;
    $('.moneyline').each(function(){
        var price = parseInt($(this).find('.price'), 10);
        var quantity = parseInt($(this).find('.quantity'), 10);
        total+= quantity*price;
    });
    alert( total );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding a class to each element that you want to count and see the answer below on stackoverflow. You should be able to have a counter for each occurrence of the class and show this variable in the html

[How to getElementByClass instead of GetElementById with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933602/how-to-getelementbyclass-instead-of-getelementbyid-with-javascript)

`<div class="item"> ... <your inputs> ... </div>`