# Getting the cell of a <tr> that has particular className

Tags: javascript, jquery

What i'm trying to do is to get the cell of this  where the classname is "revision_id".

```
<tr>
    <td class="supplierOrderId">10790</td>
    <td class="revision_id">#7</td>
    <td class="supplier">DGI Developpement </td>
    <td class="quantity">80</td>
    <td class="stock">0</td>
    <td class="purchase_price">10.00</td>
    <td class="comments"> </td>
</tr>
```

I managed to do it this way :

```
revision = this.parentNode.parentNode;
revisionId = revision.cells[1].innerHTML.replace( /[^\d.]/g, '' );
```

(cause I wanna get the int of the string)

```
iRevisionId = parseInt(revisionId);
```

Is there a more proper way to do it, with the given className ?
Because in the case where someone adds a cell before mine in the future, my code is going to be "deprecated".

Hope i've given all the details,

Thanks by advance.

```
// More Details //
```

The problem with most answers is that they work only if I have 1 `<tr>`. Once I get multiple, it gets every revisionID like this :

```
console.log(result) -> #1#2#3#4
```

(if I have 4  `<tr>` for exemple)

So this is why I am getting the GOOD one like this :
`revision = this.parentNode.parentNode;` // outputs the good `<tr>`

but after that, I can't get the  with the given className.

Comment: you forgot the closing tag of the last `td`, eg. comments!

Comment: I updated the post, cause most ansers consider I only have a single "tr".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this is tr

```
var data = $(this).children(".revision_id").text()
```

Comment: Okay I managed to make yours work this way :
$(this.parentNode.parentNode).children(".revision_id").text();

Answer (score 0):

you can do via jquery like this:

```
 var value= parseInt($(".vision_id").text().match(/[0-9]+/g)[0]);
```

[**FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9CEjJ/)

Answer (score 0):

Using the `text()` method, you can get the text inside your `td` element.
After that just parse it like you did with `parseInt()`

```
$(function() {
    var quantity = $('tr td.quantity').text();
    console.log(parseInt(quantity));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on whether you can use jQuery or not.

### Pure JavaScript

With pure JS, provided you're using a modern browser, you can use the `getElementsByClassName` function. For the purpose of this demonstration, I've assumed you have an ID on your table you can use.

```
var myClassName = 'revision_id';
var table = document.getElementById('mytable');
// the desired TD
var td = table.getElementsByClassName( myClassName ) );
```

See [Mozilla's docs on getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName).

Also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1933623/1203825) works with backwards compatibility.

### jQuery

Of course, this becomes easier with jQuery:

```
var $td = $('#mytable td.revision_id');
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/uJB2y/1/

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want it with jquery then you can use `.filter()` method:

```
 var text = $('td').filter(function () {
     return this.className === 'revision_id';
 }).text().slice(1);
 text = +text; // conversion for int
 alert(text);
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W6tCn/)