# Add new ID for every new loop

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm developing a sort of loop using `li` tags. For this loop, I'm going to use some text that gonna be displayed through a simple open and close JavaScript code that I've made when clicking somewhere. As you guys know, this kind of code is manipulated through `getElementById` property. However, since I'm going loop these lists items, I cannot repeat IDs throughout them. So, how can I loop these list items without repeating the ID?

Take the HTML below:

```
<section class="pro-further">
  <span>Consulte</span><br>
  <ul>
    <li><div onClick="furtherInfo('test');">Info one</div>
      <div id="test">Text for first info</div>
    </li>
    <li><div>Info two</div>
      <div>Text for second info</div>
    </li>
    <li><div>Info three</div>
      <div>Text for third info</div>
    </li>
    <li><div>Info four</div>
      <div>Text for fourth info</div>
    </li>
    <li><div>Info five</div>
      <div>Text for fifth info</div>
    </li>
    <li><div>Info six</div>
      <div>Text for sixth info</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

The JavaScript...

```
var furtherInfo = function(auei) {
  var openInfo = document.getElementById(auei);
  if(openInfo.style.display == "block") {
    openInfo.style.display = "none"
  }else {
    openInfo.style.display = "block"
  }
}
```

And the CSS

```
.pro-further ul {
  width:100%;
  list-style-type:none;
  margin-left:0px;
}

.pro-further ul li > div {
  width:99.3%;
  font-size:14px;
  color:#FFF;
  background:url(../images/plus2.png) #23459F no-repeat 99% 50%;
  padding:6px 2px 6px 5px;
  margin-bottom:3px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.pro-further ul li > div + div {
  width:98.5%;
  font-size:13px;
  color:#737373;
  background:white;
  border:1px solid #23459F;
  padding:2px 5px 2px 5px;
  margin-top:-3px;
  display:none;
  cursor:text;
}
```

Thank you!

[Check here to try out](http://codepen.io/caioferrari/pen/kxocf)

Comment: It is illegal to give the same ID to multiple DOM elements, anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an ID-less solution:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        elems[i].onclick = toggle;
    }
};

function toggle() {
    var divs = this.getElementsByTagName("div");
    divs[1].style.display = ((divs[1].style.display == "block") ? "none" : "block");
}
```

To restrict the "getElementsByTagName", I'd suggest giving your outer container (the one with `class="pro-further"` an ID, so it would look like `<section id="pro-further-toggles">` so then you could specify `var elems = document.getElementById("pro-further-toggles").getElementsByTagName("li");`

Answer (score 2):

You could give each item a class and then loop through them using `document.getElementsByClassName()`

See more info here:
[How to getElementByClass instead of GetElementById with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933602/how-to-getelementbyclass-instead-of-getelementbyid-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You could, in this case, just use DOM traversal, assuming the sibling-relationship is constant:

```
var furtherInfo = function(el) {
    var openInfo = el.nextElementSibling;
  openInfo.style.display = openInfo.style.display == 'block' ? 'none' : 'block'
}
```

Assuming HTML such as:

```
<ul>
    <li><div onClick="furtherInfo(this);">Info one</div>
      <div id="test">Text for first info</div>
    </li>
    <li><div onClick="furtherInfo(this);">Info two</div>
      <div>Text for second info</div>
    </li>
    <!-- and so on... -->
  </ul>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/e3Rna/).