# check if html have a class and if is true print a result without jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi can someone show me how is possible to check if some class exists and if is true return a variable? (div, a, span, b, p, etc.) **without div id and without jquery**. I am new in javascript, thanks

My prototype example

```
var button  = ".button {border: 1px solid #000, padding 1em}";

if ( button class exist in current html)
{ print var button }
```

Comment: What  exactly does "some class exists in html document" mean? Elements that have that class?

Comment: Try using document.querySelectorAll() :- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to getElementByClass instead of GetElementById with Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933602/how-to-getelementbyclass-instead-of-getelementbyid-with-javascript)

Comment: yes if the document have x class and if they exist print a variable

Comment: @RamanathanMuthuraman: `document.querySelector(klass)` is easier than `document.querySelectorAll(klass).length` :)

Answer (score 3):

`getElementsByClassName` is what you're looking for. It returns an array like object which you can simply check it's `length` to see if the class exists.

Answer (score 1):

you can check it with

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("example");
if(x!==null) 
{
  //do something
}
```

Comment: i test the solution but when i delete the example class the script continue show the alert i use to test with your example, thanks for your awnser!

Comment: The result of `getElementsByClassName` will always be a `HTMLCollection` (possibly with `.length == 0`), never `null`.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('button');
```

This returns empty if no element was found in the document. You could use it to check.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('button')` or `document.querySelectorAll('.button') (or `querySelectorAll`). Note which one has the dot, and which hasn't.

Comment: Thanks, minor issue with copy & paste.